# Tabulator - Configuration variables

Tags: tabulator

I am a beginner with Tabulator.
I have some tables that I need to configure in the same way.
Instead to do for every table the settings like this:

```
tablename1 = new Tabulator("#tablename1", {
    height:370,
    pagination:"local",
    paginationAddRow:"table",
    paginationSize:10,
    movableColumns:true,
    layout:"fitDataFill",
    placeholder:"Nessun dato",
    locale:"it-it",
    langs:MagoTabulatorLangITA,
    
    ajaxConfig:"POST", //ajax HTTP request type
    ajaxContentType:"json", 

    persistence:{
        sort: true, //persist column sorting
        group: true, //persist row grouping
        columns: true, //persist columns
    },

});
```

}

I wish to have something like:
tablename1 = new Tabulator("#tablename1", {
variable_containing_above_settings,
}

Is it possible?
Thank you very much for your help!
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question you want something like ...

```
let config = { height: 370, pagination: "local" ... };

new Tabulator("#somedivA",{ height:config.height, pagination: config.pagination, ...} );
new Tabulator("#somedivB",{ height:260, pagination: config.pagination, ...} );
new Tabulator("#somedivC",{ height:config.height, pagination: "remote", ...} );
```

Comment: Yes you could do new Tabulator("somedivA",config); new Tabulator("somedivB", config); if you wanted them all the be EXACTLY the same , but I doubted you wanted that, so I didnt do that

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for your kindly suggestion. This helped me.